# Android studio installation issues

Tags: android-studio, installation

I am not able to set the installation location on Android Studio. Also when I open the installation setup, I'm not able to view the license agreement.

I get the following:

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see this the first time and it looks strange, but...

I hope you've already installed Oracle Java 8. If not, you would find it here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

You don't need to install Android Studio. On Google's site there available also `.zip` file, which you need only unpack and run.

Look here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

Direct link: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.5.1.0/android-studio-ide-141.2456560-windows.zip

Hope it help

Comment: Yes I have installed java 8! I wonder why I'm unable to view the license agreement as well! I need the android studio IDE

Comment: Calm down ;-) For installing Android Studio for Windows uses .NET Framework, for run Java. You can't see these views because of broken installer. I don't suppose that your NET libraries are broken, but notice that it is also a possible option

Comment: Hope that my answer would help you to install Android Studio and you would able to start your mobile development journey